# html select change not triggered on click in firefox 40.0.2

Tags: firefox, select

dropdown item click does not work in Firefox 40.0.2, but select a dropdown (using up/down arrow) and click enter trigger the change event.

There is no console error seen. The same works in all other browsers and firefox other versions.

The stranger thing noted here is, it works for a dropdown in a different page.

Looks like this is bug in firefox, anyone faced this issue? is there a temporary workaround someone applied.

Reference: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1077858

Answer (score 0):

We figured out that there was a 'mouseup' listener attached to document that did event.preventDefault  which caused this problem in firefox 40.0.2.

```
$(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    /**  some code here */
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Luckily for us that e.preventDefault was unwanted, so removing it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [Site compatibility for Firefox 40](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/40/Site_Compatibility) where I found [this particular bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1194733). Could be fixed really soon.